# How to select all items when I click on all from dropdown list using jquery and selectize.js?

Tags: jquery, multi-select, selectize.js

I am having an issue to display all the items from dropdown when I click on all. Basically, I have implemented multiselect using https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/. I just want when user click on all option from dropdown then all the items from dropdown list should be display in mutliselect box instead of all option as display in image. Can anyone help me. Thanks[image]

```
html 

<select data-placeholder="Type here to find device" id="logs"  name="tags[]"  multiple class="chosen-select form-control" onchange="checkLogging()" required>
<option value="" selected></option>
<option value="ALL">All</option>
<option value="ASA" >Cisco ASA</option>
<option value="ISE"> CISCO ISE</option>
<option value="MS">Microsoft Windows</option>
<option value="ATA">Microsoft ATA</option>
<option value="Alliance">SWIFT Alliance</option>
<option value="Proxy">Bluecoat Proxy</option>
<option value="Csp"> Symantec CSP</option>
</select>
```

js

```
$(function() {
    var filter = $('#logs');
    filter.on('change', function() {
      if (this.selectedIndex) return; //not `Select All`
      filter.find('option:gt(0)').prop('selected', true);
      filter.find('option').eq(0).prop('selected', false);
    });
  });
```

Comment: @palaѕн Ok. I a going now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(function() {
   var filter = $('#logs');
   filter.on('change', function() {
      if ($(this).val() == ",ALL") {
         filter.val('').trigger('chosen:updated');
         filter.find('option:not([value="ALL"])').attr('selected', 'selected');
         filter.trigger('chosen:updated');
      }
   });
});
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mv5ztq4h/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I want to show items in select box instead of displaying in different div If u check the above image then u will get idea. Can u please help me here?